# Working load limit of chains and DOT regulations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, everyday-life

So in the department of transportation safety regulations book at 393.106-{d}

{1}:One-half the working load limit of each tiedown that goes from an anchor point on the vehicle to an anchor point on an article of cargo.

{2}:One-half the working load limit of each tiedown that is attached to an anchor point on the vehicle, passes through , over, or around the article of cargo, and is then attached to an anchor point on the same side of the vehicle.

{3}: The working load limit for each tiedown that goes from an anchor point on the vehicle, through, over, or around the article of cargo, and then attaches to another anchor point on the other side of the vehicle.

Why do I only have half the Working load limit
 of the chain in the first 2 but not the third one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about decisions behind government regulations and not physics.

Comment: Sorry as I'm a little late on the reply, I wanted to know if there was a physics related reason to why the government regulation was put in place. I am sorry if that is against the terms of service, please forgive me.

Comment: I don't think this is against terms of service in the normal sense of the meaning, it's just not on-topic (you can read [more here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the tiedowns of the first two cases only restrict movement of the load in one direction, unlike the tiedowns of case 3. See this [link](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2006/06/22/06-5236/parts-and-accessories-necessary-for-safe-operation-protection-against-shifting-and-falling-cargo): "Although mismatching of tiedowns could potentially result in real-world securement issues, the Agency believes § 393.106(d) concerning aggregate WLL deters such practices for what is commonly referred to as direct tiedowns. The rule effectively requires that tiedowns on opposite sides of the load have similar ratings in order to meet the minimum aggregate WLL. "